# Another proof of Wilson's theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Here is a list of the proof of Wilson's theorem, $\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}i=-1\bmod p$, which I know. Do you know any other proof?

1: $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group for multiplication. The order is $p-1$. Thus, by using the generator, $g$, and Fermat's little theorem, we get
$\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}i=g^{0+1+...+p-1}\equiv g^{p(p-1)/2}\equiv g^{(p-1)/2}\equiv-1$.

2: From Fermat's little theorem and factor theorem, $(x-1)...(x-p+1)=x^{p-1}-1 \bmod p$ is satisfied for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. By comparing the constant term, we get Wilson's theorem.

3: Since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is group for multiplication, for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ except $a=1,p-1$, we can make a pair $(a,a^{-1})$ s.t. $a \not\equiv a^{-1}\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, we get Wilson's theorem.

4: Using $a(p-a)\equiv -a^2\bmod p$, we get $\prod_{i=1}^{p-1}i\equiv\prod_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}(-i^2)$. From Euler's criterion and factor theorem, for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $\prod_{i=1}^{(p-1)/2}(x-i^2)\equiv x^{(p-1)/2}-1$ is satisfied. Thus, by comparing constant term, we get Wilson's theorem.

5: Consider $p$ vertices placed on a circle at regular intervals. Then the number of ways to make a Hamilton cycle is $(p-1)!$. The number of graphs which does not change even if we rotate it by $2\pi/p$ is $p-1$. Thus, the number of graphs which will change by rotating $2\pi/p$ is $(p-1)!-(p-1)$. If we collect graphs which will match each other by rotating $(2\pi/p)\mathbb{Z}$ from this $(p-1)!-(p-1)$ graphs, the size of the set is $p$. Thus we get $(p-1)!-(p-1)\equiv0\bmod p$. This is nothing but Wilson's theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem#Proofs gives a proof using the Sylow theorems

Comment: 3 is wrong $a=1$

Comment: I fix it. Thank you.